# binddata saving data before save() is called

Tags: grails

I am facing a really strange scenario with grails.

Here is the situation.

I call the controller method

```
controller.updateQuestion(question.id)
```

Now in the controller I used

```
//here question is first retrieved from as def question = Question.get(id)
binddata(question, params)
```

Now after the above code I do

```
question.validate()
```

And then check if question has errors. If it does, then it returns without saving i.e

```
question.save(flush:true)
```

Now here is what I do. I call controller.updateQuestion(question.id) sending parameters that has an error(one of the paramters has an error so this function shouldn't succeed.i.e it shouldn't update the question)

The strange thing is it seems to not reach the point where I have

```
question.save(flush:true)
```

Yet it is saving the parameter values to the domain object.

So, my doubt is, is binddata(question, params) doing the save?

Comment: "So, my doubt is, is binddata(question, params) doing the save?" - No, bindData is not saving anything.  You haven't given enough surrounding context to say for sure but I expect that your changes are being saved when the session is flushed.  The particulars will depend on which version o fGrails you are using. https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11797 and/or https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11536 may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options.  One is to roll the transaction back if you get to a state where you want to unwind the changes...

```
class SomeController {
    def someAction() {
        SomeDomain.withTransaction { tx ->
            // retrieve a persistent instance and mutate it

            // check to see if everything is ok

            if(somethingWentWrong) {
                tx.setRollbackOnly()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: question.discard() seems to do the trick. so i am guessing like you said the changes are saved when session is flushed...btw i am using grails 2.2